# API call inside setTimeout React hook displays a stale value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise, use-http

I have a custom hook for calling an API every 5 seconds. The following code works, but the `res` console.log is the same value every time. I am expecting it to show a time counted down. I have verified that the API works - if I hit it in any other way, I see a different value each time.

I am using the `use-http` library for my `useFetch` call.

```
const useSession = () => {

  const request = useFetch('', { headers: getHeaders() })

  const checkTime = () => {
    console.log('calling')
    request.get('/api/users/session/status/')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res: ', res)
        // update state here
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => checkTime(), 5000)
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, [request, checkTime])

}
```

Comment: what are those headers?  Possible you're getting a cached response?

Comment: If you're talking about calling every 5 seconds should you not be using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` ?

Comment: The headers function adds `Content-Type` as `application/json` and attached the csrf token with `'X-CSRFToken'`. I have tried making the call manually snd it does not appear to be cached, although I'm not sure where to troubleshoot in the hook to check for this.

Comment: @SakoBu my understanding is that recursive setTimeout is better practice than setInterval - [for example](https://chrisblackwell.me/setinterval-is-bad/). I am looking for the best "hooks" approach.

Comment: The link you provided uses an IIFE - see my attempt below... obviously using a different API and fetch but the concept is the same... seems to work... sends a request every 5s

Answer (score 0):

Try using checkTime inside your useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function getStatus() {
      const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
      const json = await res.json();

      setTimeout(getStatus, 5000);
      console.log('ran', json);
    })();
  }, []);
  return <div>See console</div>;
}
```

Live demo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ixhjtb

Comment: I get linter warnings whenever I try to do an IIFE or async/await call like this inside useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

The browser was caching the request - in the end I was able to workaround this by adding a timestamp as a URL parameter:

```
const timestamp = new Date()
request.get(`/api/users/session/status/?=${timestamp.getTime()}`)
```

I did try modifying the cache-related request headers, but none seemed to have any effect.